# Access ApplicationContext from junit class without any @SpringBootTest, @RunWith test annotation

Tags: spring-boot, junit

Hi I want to access `ApplicationContext` in spring boot application junit test, I tried below -

```
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    AppContext.getInstance().setContext(applicationContext);
```

AppContext.java

```
   public enum AppContext {
     INSTANCE;
     public static AppContext getInstance() {
       return INSTANCE;
     }
     public void setContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
       this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
     }

     public ApplicationContext getContext() {
       return applicationContext;
     }
   }
```

Junit Test Class

```
   public class SampleApplicationITCase {
       @BeforeClass
       public static void setUp() throws Exception {
          ApplicationContext context = AppContext.getInstance().getContext();
          myClass = context.getBean(MyClass.class); // Getting Null for context here
       }
   }
```

I have below blocking queue in my application where I am getting `java.lang.InterruptedException`

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true){
        try {
            String message = sampleQueue.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (isNull(message)){
                continue;
            }
            process(message);
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
            log.error("Failed to poll record from queue ", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that, I am starting my application before running the junit test.

I don't want to use `@SpringBootTest`, `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` because I am already using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` (thread) in my application and if I use these annotations I am getting `java.lang.InterruptedException`because these annotation will start context again or start the application again, please correct me if it is not correct.

My question is how can access `ApplicationContext` in junit without any test annotation in Spring Boot App.

Comment: You can use your own executor service, you probably have an issue there. You can't "run your application" and then expect a test you start in a separate process to be able to access that app context.

Comment: Hi dainu, thank you for looking into it. I have `start-service.sh` script which run before junit. I have updated the question where I am getting error when I use `@SpringBootTest, @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` these annotations. Can you please let me know how to start application context by avoiding error.